# error while mapping class to SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a class to SelectListItem like this :

```
return Json(id == null
                ? Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()
                : Find<BusLineRouteStop>.All.Where(x => x.Template.Id == id)
                    .MapTo<BusLineRouteStop, SelectListItem>());
```

And getting this:

Error: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: BusLineRouteStop -> SelectListItem

Comment: can you post the `BusLineRouteStop` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you haven't specified the mapping rule (system doesn't know which values of `BusLineRouteStop` are corresponding to values of `SelectListItem`. You can do it in another way, if this is one-time event:

```
return Json(id == null
                ? Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()
                : Find<BusLineRouteStop>.All.Where(x => x.Template.Id == id).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.BusLineStopValue,
                    Text = x.BusLineStopName,
                    Disabled = false,
                    Selected = false
                });
```

**P.S.** I have used the imaginary fields of `BusLineRouteStop` to demonstrate the opportunities.